# How can you configure WildFly to print runtime exceptions?

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-11

The environment is a Java program deployed in WildFly 11.0.0.Final and a terminal window that started `standalone.sh` and remains open showing the output.

Explicit output such as [`PrintStream#println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) and [`Throwable#printStackTrace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) is printed as expected, but when runtime exceptions such as [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) are thrown which naturally are not caught and thus not explicitly printed, nothing is printed. Right now I am forced to catch runtime exceptions and print them, which obviously is bothersome.

Is there a way to make WildFly print the stack trace of runtime exceptions automatically as one would expect it to do?

Comment: Are the uncaught exceptions being written to a log? What does your logging configuration look like?

Comment: @JimGarrison I have not configured any logging. As far as I can tell there is only the default `server.log` which shows the same thing as the terminal output.

Comment: What are you developing?  I've seen the type of behavior you're seeing with JAX-RS - it wants to return a 500 to the front end and it ends up not logging quite the way I want.

Comment: @stdunbar I am using Java WebSockets. The runtime exceptions are thrown inside [`onMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/MessageHandler.Whole.html#onMessage-T-).

Comment: And your code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread start");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Throw exception");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
};

Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Uncaught thread " + t + " exception: " + e);
    }
};

thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler);
thread.start();
```

Comment: This is a workaround rather than a solution. Runtime exceptions won't exist in production either way, and during development it is sufficient to wrap everything in one big try-catch if you are looking for a workaround I think. I am looking for a way to configure WildFly to print the stack traces as one would expect it to do.